# View matrix needed for eye tracking scenario

Tags: javascript, math, 3d, three.js

I am busy working on a small project where by I wont to use a webcam to track a users 'eye position' (vector from persons eye position relative to the center of the screen) and use this 'camera angle' to manipulate a threeJS scene (or maybe just straight WebGL) such that it looks like the screen itself is a 'window' into a 3d environment.  Too accomplish this I believe all that is required (assuming you already have the 'eye camera angle') is to manipulate the view matrix.  For instance the image on the left would be a typical view frustum for a standard view matrix given a straight camera angle.  The image on the right would be the ideal matrix and resulting view frustum if the 'eye camera position' were moved upwards.

[image]

Is this as simple as swapping out the standard view matrix used?
What would said matrix look like.

Please bare in mind when answering, that I know as much about linear algebra as a first grader.
Also for further details, this project will be browser based using WebGL and JavaScript.

BTW I just found out, that what I'm trying to do here is called: 'Head-coupled perspective'

Comment: What limited knowledge I do have tells me that what you are saying is exactly what I had in mind, on both counts, but I seriously lack the math knowledge to figure out how build a matrix like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a complete answer but ... at the moment I'm too lazy/busy but if I understand correctly you basically want a function like [`glFrustum`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glFrustum.xml). The math is there but the formatting is poor. This lets you generate a frustum matrix where the eye is not in the center (like the perspective function does). Three.js has support for that as well in [`Camera.setViewOffset`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.setViewOffset).

To use `Camera.setViewOffset` basically you define a larger view and the which sub portion of the three.js canvas the canvas represents of that larger view. In this case we don't care about a larger view so we can just set the larger view and sub view to the same size but still offset the smaller view.

So, effectively to match to the user's eye position you'd want to both choose a center area inside the larger area **and** move the camera.

What I'm too lazy to do at the moment is to figure out how much to move each. It seems like they'd be the same though except the camera moves in world units and `setViewOffset` works in pixels. CSS pixels are supposed to be 96 per inch so for each inch the eye moves we need offset the view the opposite direction 96 * eye inches moved.

We'd also need to know how far way the user's eyes are from the screen **and** how big the screen is so we can compute a field of view for the screen. 60inch TV with a user standing 3ft away would have a differnt field of view a user in front of an 11inch notebook with their face 1ft away

```js
let mouse = new THREE.Vector2(), INTERSECTED;
let radius = 100, theta = 0;

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, 1, 1, 10000);

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xf0f0f0);

const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 ).normalize();
scene.add( light );

const geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(1, 1, 1);

for (let z = 0; z < 50; ++z) {
  for (let y = -1; y <= 1; ++y) {
    for (let x = -1; x <= 1; ++x) {
      if (x === 0 && y === 0) {
         continue;
      }
      const object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: Math.random() * 0xffffff}));
  
      object.position.x =  x * 1.5;
      object.position.y =  y * 1.5;
      object.position.z = -z * 2.5;

      scene.add(object);
    }
  }
}

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.querySelector("canvas")});
resize(true);
document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

requestAnimationFrame(render);

function resize(force) {
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;
  if (force || canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height) {
    renderer.setSize(width, height, true);
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
}

function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  // compute mouse movement in inches
  mouse.x = (event.clientX - canvas.clientWidth  / 2) / 96;
  mouse.y = (event.clientY - canvas.clientHeight / 2) / 96;
}

function render(time) {
  const worldUnits = 1;
  const pixelUnits = worldUnits * 96;  

  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  const fullWidth  = canvas.clientWidth;
  const fullHeight = canvas.clientHeight;
  const aspect = fullWidth / fullHeight;
  
  const eyeOffsetX = mouse.x;
  const eyeOffsetY = mouse.y;
  
  const eyeDistFromScreenInches = 12;
  const halfHeightOfScreenInches = fullHeight / 96 * .5;
  const halfFov = Math.atan2(halfHeightOfScreenInches, eyeDistFromScreenInches) * 180 / Math.PI;
  const width   = fullWidth;
  const height  = fullHeight;
  const centerX = fullWidth / 2;
  const centerY = fullHeight / 2;
  const left    = centerX - width /  2 - eyeOffsetX * pixelUnits;
  const top     = centerY - height / 2 - eyeOffsetY * pixelUnits;
  
  camera.fov = halfFov * 2;  
  camera.position.x =  eyeOffsetX * worldUnits;
  camera.position.y = -eyeOffsetY * worldUnits;
  
  camera.setViewOffset(fullWidth, fullHeight, left, top, width, height);
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/87/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: I will have a look at this when I get a chance, but it sounds like the solution im looking for.

Comment: So I have taken in initial look and it looks like its exactly what I wanted, thanks.  As for the comment about actual depth calculations, I figured I would have to 'guess' that anyway, although maybe at some point, I will hook this project up to google tango hardware to get actual distance information :)

Comment: btw: There's a library, [headtrackr.js](https://github.com/auduno/headtrackr). It [links to a sample](https://auduno.github.com/headtrackr/examples/targets.html). Looking in the library I see [similar code](https://github.com/auduno/headtrackr/blob/5f62f4c471d2b2ebae4f05c7b1123400c1bb520f/src/controllers.js#L51)